Getting into grad school after online undergraduate
I am currently doing Bsc computer science from an university which has offline, hybrid and online modes. I have done 3 semesters through online and have the chance to do the remaining offline. However, due to personal reasons I have to finish my bachelor's full online. How will this affect an application for grad school? The three modes provide the same degree (no writings like online degree, offline degree etc).
Further, due to this, it kind of limited my chance of getting good recommendation letters from professors because I couldn't directly interact with them directly like the offline people. Is it okay to get a decent recommendation letter from 1 professor and the rest from a previous internship manager, junior research associate at another university (at my home) with whom I did a research internship? What approaches do I have to strengthen my application for graduate school?

This might depend on the country in which you want to apply. Which is it?

UK graduate school.

While I don't think this is a duplicate, see the answer for UK here:https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368

same goes for: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/38237/how-are-ph-d-applications-evaluated-in-the-us-particularly-for-weak-or-borderl

Ask.
Pick a graduate school you might want to apply to and ask the admissions office precisely this question. They will know what they think of all-online degrees and will be delighted to explain. They might for instance say that they have found online degrees equivalent in some ways and lacking in others - so that you can think about how to plug those gaps.
I have known this to work in various sets of “non-standard” circumstances. The key is that you are doing this at the right time. You are not (yet) applying, so you are not in any way bypassing the standard procedures — nor are you asking for special consideration, since you are not being considered at all.
